# Why is the angular average of the direction of the momentum squared a third instead of one?

Tags: momentum, vectors, integration, calculus

In the article http://www.nano.northwestern.edu/intranet/pubdocs/quasiclassical.pdf (in going from eq. (6.13) to eq. (6.14)) it is stated that
$$\langle\hat{p}\cdot\hat{p}\rangle_{\hat{p}}=\dfrac{1}{3},$$
where $\langle\cdots\rangle_{\hat{p}}$ denotes the angular average:
$$\langle f(\vec{p})\rangle_{\hat{p}}=\displaystyle\int\dfrac{d\Omega_p}{4\pi}\,f(\vec{p}).$$
In words, the angular average of the dot product of the direction of the momentum (in this case the Fermi momentum) equals a third. This seems odd to me, as I'd expect
$$\langle\hat{p}\cdot\hat{p}\rangle_{\hat{p}}=\langle1\rangle_{\hat{p}}=1.$$
Where do I go wrong, why is the result a third?

Comment: Betohaku: "_In the article http://www.nano.northwestern.edu/intranet/pubdocs/quasiclassical.pdf it is stated that_" $$\langle \hat p \cdot \hat p \rangle_{\hat p} = \frac{1}{3}.$$
 -- Would you please point out exactly which number this equation has in the article mentioned? (I'm more familiar with the factor $1/3$ arising in certain averages of $\vec p \cdot \vec p$, rather than $\hat p \cdot \hat p$ ...)

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to specify that, silly me. Thanks for noting.

Comment: Betohaku: With your added guidance (+1) I also find explicitly (on p. 20, following eq. (6.1)) that ["_{...} $\hat p$ denotes a vector of unit magnitude in the direction of $\vec p$_"](http://www.nano.northwestern.edu/intranet/pubdocs/quasiclassical.pdf). Now: I can't help but notice that $$\frac{1}{4 \pi}~\int_0^{2 \pi} {\rm d}\phi \int_0^{\pi} \text{Sin}[~\theta~]~{\rm d \theta}~(\text{Cos}[~\theta~])^2 = \frac{1}{4 \pi}~\int_0^{2 \pi} {\rm d}\phi~\frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}.$$ (But I have far too little experience with these sort of calculations to claim that this was actually intended. ...)

Comment: @user12262 I get the same result for that integral, but where does that $\cos^2\theta$ come from? Somehow a factor $\cos\theta$ for each $\hat{p}$? (I do get zero for integrating $\cos\theta$):
$$\dfrac{1}{4\pi}\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}d\pi\displaystyle\int_0^\pi d\theta\sin\theta\cos\theta=\dfrac{1}{4}\displaystyle\int_0^\pi d\theta\sin(2\theta)=\dfrac{1}{8}\left[-\cos(2\theta)\right]_0^\pi.$$

Comment: Betohaku: "_but where does that $\text{cos}^2 \theta$ come from?_" -- That's the big, fair question which I don't know how to seriously answer either. "_Somehow a factor $\text{cos} \theta$ for each $\hat p$ ?_" -- And correspondingly interpreting "the dot product" $\hat p \cdot \hat p$ as plain square of this factor. Well, perhaps this has something to do with "[direction cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine#General_meaning)". Perhaps the case can be made that this was intended in the article, and (moreover) is also correct. But I cannot make that case, as a serious answer.

Comment: @user12262 Having stared at it for a while I think the problem is actually in the divergence, which changes the question a lot (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/214498/why-does-the-angular-average-of-the-divergence-result-in-a-factor-1-3), I think I'll delete this one in a bit (it'll only lead to confusion).